# How do I delete a default "scope link" route?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have the following routes listed on my device:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route list
default dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link
default via 192.168.1.5 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
169.254.0.0/16 dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link src 169.254.207.114 metric 202
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
```

That first listed route is *incorrect*. This device can't access the rest of the world through its ethernet port, but only though wifi. However, I seem unable to remove this route:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip route del default scope link && ip route
default dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link
default via 192.168.1.5 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
169.254.0.0/16 dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link src 169.254.207.114 metric 202
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip route del default dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link && ip route
default dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link
default via 192.168.1.5 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
169.254.0.0/16 dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link src 169.254.207.114 metric 202
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link && ip route
default dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link
default via 192.168.1.5 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
169.254.0.0/16 dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link src 169.254.207.114 metric 202
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.197 metric 303
```

This route interferes with the ability to reach the wider world:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 dev enxb827eb4e4311 src 169.254.207.114 uid 1000
    cache
```

I think I'm specifying the route correctly because if I specify a route that doesn't exist I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 dev enxb827eb4e4311 scope link && ip route
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

From another answer I got the hint to do `ip addr flush dev enxb827eb4e4311`, but I don't want to remove the IP address on the device and I also don't want to remove the route with metric 202.

How do I remove this bad route, or failing that get useful information about why I can't?

Comment: Weird. Does `ip route del default dev enxb827eb4e4311` work? I wonder why your network manager adds a default route that uses `enxb827eb4e4311` when it configures ["auto IP"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4) on the interface. What do you use to manage your network interfaces?

Comment: Doesn't work; same result. (Command seems to succeed, but the route is still there).

Comment: The addresses are managed by `dhcpcd 8.1.2`.

Comment: The really odd thing is that this bad route isn't there at first; at first boot, the WiFi isn't active (I have to log in via the Ethernet link and activate it). Before I activate the WiFi, the only route is the one shown with metric 202. Once I activate the WiFi, the other three routes shown appear.

Comment: `I have to log in via the Ethernet link and activate it` What exactly is the context here? I mean like, how are the two networks your host connected related? I have never heard of anything like that.

Comment: The ethernet connection is a temporary debugging connection I don't intend to leave in place. I've separately got to figure out why the wifi hardware isn't initializing properly at boot, but until then I need to do a dance to get wifi up after each reboot.

Comment: Did you actually mean like you are relying on the ethernet link to ssh/remote in? (I was thinking of some really quirky captive portal or so.)

Answer (score 0):

One link-scope route is generated from the prefix length (i.e. subnet mask) that was provided when assigning the address to the `enx` interface. Having a link-scope 'default' route (i.e. a `0.0.0.0/0` route) almost always means you provided a prefix length of `/0` when assigning the address – so if you don't want that to happen, you'll need to provide a prefix length other than /0.

For example, this would result in an 172.16.5.0/24 route being generated instead:

```
ip addr del 172.16.5.7 dev enx && ip addr add 172.16.5.7/24 dev enx
```

If you wanted to assign a single address without it implying a subnet, a full-length /32 prefix (the opposite of /0) should typically be used.

Comment: I didn't assign the address; it was assigned automatically by the dhcp client; there's no dhcp server connected on that iFace, so it gets the automatic address in the 169.254.*.* range.